# How can I filter by Fargate service in event bridge pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I have an Eventbridge rule which trigger a lambda function every time a task crashed in the cluster `PRODUCTION`.
The issue is that I want to monitor only tasks running in the specific service `backendPRODUCTION`.
I didn't find any template specifying an ECS service with Eventbridge. How can I trigger my lambda function only for tasks running in the specific service `backendPRODUCTION`?

Thanks in advance!

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail-type": ["ECS Task State Change", "ECS Container Instance State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": ["arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-3:xxxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/PRODUCTION"],
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "stoppedReason": [
      "Essential container in task exited"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Tasks and services are two different things in ECS. Which one do you want to configure an event for?

Comment: Unfortunately both. I want to monitor only tasks launched by a specific service.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the "Task state change events" examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html), I'm not seeing any way to determine if a task is part of a service or not. The best thing I can think of after looking at the examples is to use a specific value in the `family` attribute of your service's tasks, which gets reported in the `group` attribute in Event Bridge, and then filter on that.